# Oracle VM CentOS8 unable to connect to internet with Bridged Adapter

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine, centos-8

I am trying to connect to the internet with a bridged wireless adapter in CentOS8 Virtual Box. I am running Windows 11. No IP Address shows up for enp0s3.

My settings:
[image: Briged Adapter, Promiscuous Mode: Allow All, Cable Connected]

Ip a:
[image: no ip address returned for enp0s3]

ifcfg-enp0s3
[image: BOOTPROTO=dhcp, ONBOOT=yes]

I have a vpn, but it is not currently active.

Comment: Its been a while since I used virtualbox but I vaguely recall wifi adaptors don't work with bridging